# php function not returning string and how to remove line breaks

Tags: php, function

Two issues with the below php function.

One problem with the below function is the function echoes the $boo and $boo2 variables where the function is (i.e. before 1 and 2 is echoed). Both functions are echoed before 1 and 2. I'm unsure how to return the variables where each function is called without prematurely ending the function with 'return'.

The $boo variables are single line breaks or paragraphs of text.

```
<?php
function listformat ($list) {
    $listformat = explode("\n", $list);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($listformat as $line) {
        echo "<li>".$line."</li>";
    };
    echo '</ul>';
};
listformat($boo);
echo '1';
listformat($boo2);
echo '2';
?>
```

Also wondering how I can remove line breaks of the $boo variables within the function when the lines of text have more than 1 line break.

EDIT: sample $boo is:

> aaaa  aaaaa
>
> bbb bbbb
>
> cccc c cc

Sometimes it can have more or less line breaks in between.

Comment: Please provide sample input of `$boo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function listformat ($list) {
    $listformat = explode("\n", $list);
    $out = '<ul>';
    foreach ($listformat as $line) {
        $out .= "<li>".$line."</li>";
    };
    $out .= '</ul>';
    return $out;
};
```

Comment: Sweet. Didn't know you could concatenate a variable like that. Now just have to remove the extra line breaks.

Comment: Where do the extra line breaks appear? Throughout the returned string or on one specific end? You may be able to use `rtrim($out,"\n")` or `ltrim($out,"\n")` if they are on the far right or left, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the whitespace (spaces, newlines, etc), you can use `trim()`:

```
$string = "Testing\n";
$new_string = trim($string);
// $new_string is now "Testing"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked at the start of the function:

```
$list = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $list);
```